# How to automatically reconcile /etc/group and /etc/gshadow

Tags: linux, shell, user-management

Running `grpck` to check the groups, I see these errors:

```
 'twinky' is a member of the 'foo' group in /etc/group but not in /etc/gshadow
 'dipsy' is a member of the 'foo' group in /etc/group but not in /etc/gshadow
 'laalaa' is a member of the 'foo' group in /etc/group but not in /etc/gshadow
 'po' is a member of the 'foo' group in /etc/group but not in /etc/gshadow
 'noonoo' is a member of the 'foo' group in /etc/group but not in /etc/gshadow
 'dipsy' is a member of the 'foo' group in /etc/group but not in /etc/gshadow
 ...
```

...and on for quite a few. I'm not sure how this happened, and I'd like to get it cleaned up. I know I could manually edit the `/etc/gshadow`, but I'd rather let the OS do it, to prevent typos and manual labor.

Is there anything that can automatically reconcile a group into gshadow? Maybe something like (making this up):

```
# grpfix foo
```

I've tried man on various group-related commands and googled around, but so far I haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**man** had the answer I missed before:

```
grpconv
```

http://linux.die.net/man/8/grpconv:

> The grpconv command creates gshadow from group and an optionally existing gshadow.